# change field from int to big int in drupal

Tags: entities

I have a integer field in a custom content type, first we did't estimate that we have a data more than `2 147 483 647`(max integer number_ , but I have some data that bigger than max integer range,
we input very data to that field and it not logic that install bigint module then remove integer field and create a bigint instead of it ( all of our data will lost),
I know I can change table in mysql database by myself,but maybe in future needs update drupal to newer version , what is your suggestion to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [bigint](https://drupal.org/project/bigint) module.

> The default core fields do not include a bigint field. This module
>   allows you to have a true BigInt (19) value. That means the number can
>   contain 19 digits.

So, with this module you can define fields with the appropiate range.

Your problem now is to migrate data from your current field to a new bigint created field.

The usual steps will be:

- Create and configure the new bigint field.
- Edit affected nodes copying data form old int field to the new bigint field (using Batch API, for example). Or using a direct SQL commands, if your are brave enough.
- Update related configuration to use the new field (for example, Views).
- Delete de old field.

Depending on your usual workflow you can do this by different means:

- Manually, closing the web during update.
- Using Features for the configuration (fields, Views, etc).
- Update script (for example, a hook_update_N if you are using a installation profile).